# Data frame grouping using Group by or Aggregate in R

Tags: r, function, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I would wish to create the following table via a current data frame that I have. My current data frame is as follows

```
ID = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5), rep("C",4))
NRT = c(3,3,4,5,5,3,3,4,3,3,5,5)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(ID,NRT))
```

| ID | NRT |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 5 |

I would like to obtain a table as follows which shows the average of NRT for each unique ID

| ID | NRT(Average) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3.33 (average of NRT for A) |
| B | 4 (average of NRT for B) |
| C | 4 (average of NRT for C) |

Thanks all for the help in advance :)

Comment: Try: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(NRT = mean(NRT))` OR `aggregate(NRT ~ ID, df, mean)`

Comment: Why comment and not put it in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider using a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame` (note that a `data.table` inherits from `data.frame`) this is most easily achieved

```r
library(data.table)

ID = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5), rep("C",4))
NRT = c(3,3,4,5,5,3,3,4,3,3,5,5)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(ID,NRT))

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, list("NRT (Average)" = mean(NRT)), by = ID]
```

```
   ID NRT (Average)
1:  A    3.333333
2:  B    4.000000
3:  C    4.000000
```

If you want the table to be printed *exactly* as you posted you can do the following

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5), rep("C",4)), NRT = c(3,3,4,5,5,3,3,4,3,3,5,5))
dt[, "NRT(Average)" := paste0(mean(NRT), " (average for NRT for ", ID, ")"), by = ID]
dt[, .SD[1], by = ID][, c(1, 3)]
```

```
   ID                             NRT(Average)
1:  A 3.33333333333333 (average for NRT for A)
2:  B                4 (average for NRT for B)
3:  C                4 (average for NRT for C)
```